# Initial Add-Migration thinks database is already up to date

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do a complete reset of EF Core code-first migrations in my project. I have a good reason to do so (can explain if needed), but am having a hard time getting it to work.

I've dropped the previous database and deleted the old migrations directory in my project.

See below log. About three quarters of the way down, you see that EF thinks the database is already up to date. However, you see that it created a fresh database at the beginning? Note: I truncated a lot at the end of the log as it is just stack trace errors because it couldn't find the table that it thought already should have existed.

Any guidance on how to re-create a fresh initial migration and update the database?

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\CollinB\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'FilterListsDbContext' using provider 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql' with options: MaxPoolSize=128 MigrationsAssembly=FilterLists.Api 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE DATABASE `filterlistsdata`;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (33ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `__EFMigrationsHistory` (
          `MigrationId` varchar(95) NOT NULL,
          `ProductVersion` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK___EFMigrationsHistory` PRIMARY KEY (`MigrationId`)
      );
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='filterlistsdata' AND TABLE_NAME='__EFMigrationsHistory';
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `MigrationId`, `ProductVersion`
      FROM `__EFMigrationsHistory`
      ORDER BY `MigrationId`;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
      **No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.**
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT CASE
          WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM `languages` AS `l`)
          THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
      END
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'filterlistsdata.languages' doesn't exist ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'filterlistsdata.languages' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't realize that the application actually runs when I run the initial add-migration. It was running some of my [seed code](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/master/src/FilterLists.Api/DbContextExtension.cs) which was causing it to fail. Temporarily commenting that out allowed my initial create to run.

Answer (score 0):

Never manually delete a Migrations folder. It will save you a lot of headache; you use code-first to create your database so use code-first to delete.

First, close visual studio and re-open it. Then try to run your migration again.

if that doesn't work, The easiest thing to do at this point, would be to go to appsettings.json and change the name of your database. Then run add-migration again and update the database.

Comment: Thanks!

The problem I ran into was that I initially created the database not encoded with utf8. Trying to use the migrations I already had against a new utf8 database errors out due to max row size issues. I tried to add a new migration adjusting the sizes of the columns in the table that failed, but since it updates the database one migration at a time when adding a migration, it error-ed out before it got to creating the new migration with the smaller columns.

I did try closing and re-opening VS as well with no luck.

I had also tried a new db name with the same error as well.

Comment: I'm not sure it's good advice to say that you should never manually delete a migrations folder. What evidence do you have to back your statement? I've successfully deleted my folder in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried almost all the ways available for the solution. Nothing worked as I am always able to see the db and only migration table is being created.

**Solution:**
I created a different solution with same *db_connection string* and build all the tables with **Add-Migration** and **Update-Database** command.
Later I used that in existing project.

Works perfectly.